# does a continous $f(x)$ limit is a necessary condition for uniform convergence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have function sequence $S =  \{f_n(x)\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$.

and $S$ converge to $f(x)$. (I mean $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) = f(x)$)

in order that $\{f_n(x) \}_{n =1}^\infty$ **converge unfirmly(uniform convergence)** to $f(x)$,

does $f(x)$ must be a continous function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Let $f_n=1_{\mathbb Q}$. Then all $f_n$ are equal, hence equal their limit and none is continuous

Comment: Can you please explain? What do you mean by "hence equal their limit and none is continuous"?